# Stoping and starting a new thread after timer expires

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

this is my first post on Stackoverflow and obviously i dont have much knowlege about threads.
Its a console app and the thing is, when the main method starts,also the timer starts and my program executes,it involves getting information from keyboard and it works great.

After timer expires,lets say after 20 sec, it calls run() from RemindTask Class and shows me number of points i gather during that time.
Now after that i want to make option **to start** or **not to start** again my app,main method.

**The thing** is my main will still gather informations from keyboard cause its still executing and not from input from run() method which i want.
If i put System.exit(0), ofcourse i cannot start a new thread after it.
How do i get pass this,is there a way to say in my while loop "Until my timer didnt expired do this"? or something?

```
static class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
             char answer;
             System.out.println("Time expired! "+yourResult);
             /* System.exit(0);
                Thread t = new Thread();
                t.start(); */
             System.out.println("Do you continue? y/n");
             Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
             answer = in.nextLine().charAt(0);
                if(answer=='y'){
                System.out.println("Continue program");
                String[] args = {}; 
                Main.main(args); 
                }else
                System.out.println("Stoping program");
                System.exit(0); //Stops the AWT thread (and everything else)
      }

        }

static int yourResult;
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int seconds=20;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds * 1000);
        boolean contin = true;  


        while(contin == true){

        //...a bunch of code...
        //...Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);..
        //...a bunch of code...

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping a thread is not a trivial task. The short answer to how to stop a thread is: do not stop a thread from within another thread; instead, *ask* the thread to stop itself. The reason for this is that a thread has to stop in a safe place. If the thread which is stopped holds a mutex, for example, a deadlock may occur if another thread also requires this mutex.

First, probably it is better that you do not use the main method for polling the keyboard. Just create another thread to do this; this makes it easier to make a new thread doing the same thing later.

Second, what you have to do is pass a reference to the main thread's `Thread` object to your `RemindTask` thread. Java offers a method `Thread.stop()` to stop a thread, but it has been deprecated for the reason I gave above.

Instead, you have to ask the main thread to stop. Java offers a standard way of doing this. You call `Thread.interrupt()` on the `Thread` instance of the main thread. Then, in the main thread you regularly call the static method `Thread.interrupted()`. If it returns `true`, this means that some other thread has asked the current thread to terminate, and you can cleanly stop by returning from the `run()` method.

Comment: Thank you i'll try that later, but is there a way to do this, as it looks like, simple task "getting program started again with keyboard input after timer expires" with not playing with threads?
I cant see a way around it.
Without keyboard input 'y' it is simple,it just calls main again after _System.out.println("Time expired! "+yourResult);_ but with this input thing it is really a nuisance.

Comment: _"You call Thread.interrupt() on the main thread. Then, in the main thread..."_ - Didn't you mean the spawned/other thread or something like that?

Comment: @DanielGomes No, it meant it as it was written, although I could have written it more clearly. I have reformulated a bit.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to get a grip on threads and I found your answer to be very helpful. Particularly the part about `Thread.stop()` - always wondered about that myself; that explanation alone is a +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to get what the problem is without the call to the RemindTask.run() method. In the commented part of your code, inside the main method loop, you have a constructor call that is also inside the RemindTask.run(). Maybe that is part of the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean or have i understood the answer,in the commented part of my code inside the main method loop i have a bunch of code which is working.
I'll try to explain better. 
Methods and keyboard input executing in my while loop, after 20 sec it calls RemindTask.run() and sayz
 _System.out.println("Time expired! "+yourResult);_ 
_System.out.println("Do you continue? y/n");_ 
When i try to insert 'y' cause i want to repeat my program,it still gathers keyboard input for methods in my while loop in main and not to store it in **char answer**

Comment: It just seems that you are opening two scanners using System.in. That's weird.